# After update to MVC 5, iframe no longer works

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iframe, asp.net-mvc-5

I updated my project MVC version to 5 and now iFrame does not load, I get this error:

**Load denied by X-Frame-Options: www.blahblah.com does not permit cross-origin framing.**

I noticed that for some reason now the X-Frame-Options header has SAMEORIGIN filled which does not allow the iframe to load a page from a different domain. This is a problem for me as I develop both the containing and inheriting page. I tried everything in IIS to change this header to no avail.

Anyone encountered this yet?

Comment: The question was just [asked again](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20254303/mvc-5-prevents-access-to-content-via-iframe), so you may want to keep an eye on that one as well.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MVC 5 prevents access to content via Iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20254303/mvc-5-prevents-access-to-content-via-iframe)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I finally found the answer. Starting with MVC 5 Microsoft decided to set SAMEORIGIN in there by default. The best way I found to turn this tag off is by writing the following in the **Global.asax.cs**

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
//Bundles and stuff are here
AntiForgeryConfig.SuppressXFrameOptionsHeader = true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your IFrame content is being served by your MVC app...

You might need to include a response header that permits cross origin requests:

Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *

Comment: I've tried adding various headers, the application slaps on SAMEORIGIN no matter what I do, and if the browser detects more than one header it errors out and slaps on DENY.