# MVC 5 prevents access to content via Iframe

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Ever since the upgrade from MVC4 to MVC5, I have noticed an extra server header added to my web pages:

X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN

I understand security benefits of adding this tag, but one of the pages is meant to be included inside an iframe from other projects (on other domains), this extra header is preventing this.

I have verified it is not the hosting IIS7 server that is adding the header, and when I downgraded back to MVC4 - the header is gone.

Does anyone know how to remove this default from MVC5?

Comment: This [same question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20253840/afer-update-to-mvc-5-iframe-no-longer-works) was just asked, so if you don't get an answer here, keep an eye on that one.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Setting Access-Control-Allow-Origin in ASP.Net MVC - simplest possible method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6290053/setting-access-control-allow-origin-in-asp-net-mvc-simplest-possible-method)

Answer (score 104, accepted):

MVC5 automatically adds the HTTP header X-Frame-Options with `SAMEORIGIN`.  This prevents your site from being loaded into an `iframe`.

But we can turn this off in `Application_Start` in the `Global.asax.cs`.

**Example**

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
    AntiForgeryConfig.SuppressXFrameOptionsHeader = true;
}
```

**Update**

I have written a post about this [MVC5 prevents your website being loaded in an IFRAME](http://www.iambacon.co.uk/blog/mvc5-prevents-your-website-being-loaded-in-an-iframe)

Comment: What if I only want to allow certain pages to be iframe loaded? Previously I had a custom attribute `AllowAnyOriginAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute`. Can I change the configuration per request, or is `Application_PreSendRequestHeaders` still preferred in this scenario (as per http://stackoverflow.com/a/20254341/65611)?

Comment: Thanks, this helper @Html.AntiForgeryToken() is what causes the header to be added.

In AntiForgeryWorker.cs:
`if (!this._config.SuppressXFrameOptionsHeader)
   httpContext.Response.AddHeader("X-Frame-Options", "SAMEORIGIN");`

Comment: You could just add this to your `web.config`
`<system.webServer>
  ...

  <httpProtocol>
    <customHeaders>
      <add name="X-Frame-Options" value="SAMEORIGIN" />
    </customHeaders>
  </httpProtocol>

  ...
</system.webServer>`

Comment: This answer requires the System.Web.Helpers namespace in your global.asax file.

Comment: Http Headers issues: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34270192/server-cannot-append-header-after-http-headers-have-been-sent-exception-at-html?noredirect=1&lq=1

Answer (score 4):

Try something like this in `Global.asax`:

```
protected void Application_PreSendRequestHeaders(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
   HttpContext.Current.Response.Headers.Remove("X-Frame-Options");
 }
```

EDIT:

Look at [answer of Colin Bacon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20254303/mvc-5-prevents-access-to-content-via-iframe/20254341#20262211). It is more correct than mine.

In short - don't remove this header if you don't want to run your site in IFRAME because it will open forgery vulnerability. But if you still want to remove it - use `AntiForgeryConfig.SuppressXFrameOptionsHeader = true;` in `Application_Start`, it is more cleaner way for doing this.

Comment: It feels a bit like a hack, right before the page is sent out, the tag is stripped, but it works, so I am accepting your answer. - It would be nice to know why the tag is being added though.

Comment: We can actually suppress this in app_start with `AntiForgeryConfig.SuppressXFrameOptionsHeader = true;`

Comment: Nice. Easy fix for a not so good code with 300 form tags with antiforgeries on each one.

Comment: Isn't this the better answer if you only want to allow some pages to be accessed via an IFrame?

Answer (score 3):

If you want a little more flexibility, here's an ActionAttribute that adds/removes headers based on a whitelist. If the referrer isn't in the whitelist, then the SAMEORIGIN header is left in place. I was going to paste the code, but SO complains about the length.

https://long2know.com/2016/06/asp-net-anti-forgery-xframe-options/

Answer (score 3):

Personally, I don't think it's a good idea to disable the X-Frame-Options across the whole site.I've created an ASP.NET MVC filter which removes this header and I simply apply this filter to the portions of the site that are used in iFrames e.g. widgets.

```
public class AllowDifferentOrigin : ActionFilterAttribute, IActionFilter
{
    public override void OnResultExecuted(ResultExecutedContext filterContext)
    {
        filterContext.HttpContext.Response.Headers.Remove("X-Frame-Options");
        base.OnResultExecuted(filterContext);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a replacement Extension method for the `HtmlHelper` class. It will first clear **all** `X-Frame-Options` headers and then add back a single `X-Frame-Options` header normally added by the built-in `AntiForgeryToken` method.

This technique respects the `SuppressXFrameOptionsHeader` setting, but has the downside of removing **all** previously added `X-Frame-Options` headers, even those with values other than `SAMEORIGIN`.

```cs
public static MvcHtmlString AntiForgeryTokenSingleHeader(this HtmlHelper html)
{
    string token = AntiForgery.GetHtml().ToString();
    HttpResponseBase httpResponse = html.ViewContext.HttpContext.Response;

    httpResponse.Headers.Remove("X-Frame-Options");
    if (!AntiForgeryConfig.SuppressXFrameOptionsHeader)
    {
        httpResponse.AddHeader("X-Frame-Options", "SAMEORIGIN");
    }
    return new MvcHtmlString(token);
}
```