# IIS is adding default 'X-Frame-Options:SAMEORIGIN' even then I added new HTTP response header in default website level as'X-Frame-Options:ALLOW'.

Tags: javascript, http-headers, iis-7.5

Hi I added new HTTP response header in default website level as'X-Frame-Options:ALLOW'. IIS is adding default 'X-Frame-Options:SAMEORIGIN' and sending both the header in response. And then browser is giving error as Multiple 'X-Frame-Options' headers with conflicting values ('SAMEORIGIN, ALLOW-FROM http://srv-ind-svt26dw.vanenburg.com:8080/') encountered when loading 'http://srv-ind-svt26dw.vanenburg.com/OTCS/livelink.exe?func=brava.bravaviewer&nodeid=18941'. Falling back to 'DENY'. Can any one help me out from this issue.

Many thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MVC 5 prevents access to content via Iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20254303/mvc-5-prevents-access-to-content-via-iframe)

Answer (score 1):

If your using ASP.NET MVC 5, it insert SAMERORIGIN by default see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20254303/mvc-5-prevents-access-to-content-via-iframe).