# X-Frame-Options not working IIS web.config

Tags: iis, x-frame-options

Our site is not currently safe from clickjacking, so I went into the *web.config* and added

```xml
<system.webServer>
    <httpProtocol>
        <customHeaders>
            <add name="X-Frame-Options" value="DENY" />
        </customHeaders>
    </httpProtocol>
</system.webServer>
```

This is very straight forward code. My issue is that **it's just not working.** The questions I have are:

1. Is there a way for me to see if the `X-Frame-Options` is in the header response? I looked for it with httpfox and got nothing, so I can't verify if the `web.config` is actually putting things in the header.
2. Why is this not working? What can I do to test or move forward?

I did try to add it in the *Global.asax* in the `Application_Start` method, but I cant seem to "hit" this method when I debug; it does not hit breakpoints.

```cs
private void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Code that runs on application startup
    HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("x-frame-options", "DENY");

    LogHelper.Info("Cost of Care Web Application Starting");
}
```

I would like to add that I have tried to add it straight into the head tag and  I've also tried to add it in a meta tag like so

```xml
<meta http-equiv="X-Frame-Options" content="deny">
```

Comment: I've had this issue before and have always found myself having to place the `X-Frame-Options` directly in code: `Response.AddHeader("X-Frame-Options", "DENY");` I couldn't tell you why it doesn't work though as the documentation makes it look like it should.

Comment: i searched my solution and found that its already implemented somewhere in the global.asax in the "application_start method .... any more options or advice?

Comment: If it's not adding it from Global.asax, what section of Global is it in?

Comment: (made an edit above) but its in the "application_start) method

Comment: Create a `protected void Application_BeginRequest(){}` method in Global.asax and add it in there.

Comment: YESSSSS!!!!! @IVA.K   THANK YOU SO MUCH THAT DID THE TRICK! how do i mark you/that as answer?

Comment: Setting it in the config file works fine for me on a web forms app running on both IIS 7.5 and IIS 10.0

Comment: Possible solution:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11048863/modules-runallmanagedmodulesforallrequests-true-meaning

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Since my comments answered the question here's the end result:

For some reason setting the `X-Frame-Options` in web.config doesn't seem to actually work even though the documentation makes it sound like it should.

An easy work around is to set the headers manually using:

```
Response.AddHeader("X-Frame-Options", "DENY");
```

If you need this set for every request with no exceptions you can add the `Application_BeginRequest` to Global.asax:

```
protected void Application_BeginRequest()
{
    Response.AddHeader("X-Frame-Options", "DENY");
}
```

Answer (score 30):

The X-Frame-Options header can be used to control whether a page can be placed in an IFRAME. Because the Framesniffing technique relies on being able to place the victim site in an IFRAME, a web application can protect itself by sending an appropriate X-Frame-Options header.

To configure IIS to add an X-Frame-Options header to all responses for a given site, follow these steps:

1. Open Internet Information Services (IIS) Manager.
2. In the Connections pane on the left side, expand the Sites folder and select the site that you want to protect.
3. Double-click the `HTTP Response Headers` icon in the feature list in the middle.
   [image]
4. In the Actions pane on the right side, click Add.
5. In the dialog box that appears, type `X-Frame-Options` in the Name field and type `SAMEORIGIN` or `DENY` in the Value field.
   [image]
6. Click OK to save your changes.

Answer (score 14):

The answer of `siva.k` does not work in connection with MVC5 as the header is generated twice here. The following code should work:

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
  //  MVC5 generates the "X-Frame-Options SAMEORIGIN" header by default, the following line disables the default behaviour
  System.Web.Helpers.AntiForgeryConfig.SuppressXFrameOptionsHeader = true;
}

protected void Application_BeginRequest() 
{
  Response.AddHeader("X-Frame-Options", "DENY");
}
```

The `SuppressXFrameOptionsHeader` flag was mentioned here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20262211/3936440

Answer (score 9):

```
<system.webServer>
    <httpProtocol>
        <customHeaders>
            <add name="Content-Security-Policy" value="default-src: https:; frame-ancestors 'self' X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN" />
        </customHeaders>
    </httpProtocol>
</system.webServer>
```

Your web.config entry needs to be under **content security policy** to make use of current coding not previously depreciated.   The value under content security policy of `value="default-src: https:` is unique to your website.

The content that matters is what comes after 'value="default-src: https:' but most importantly is contained within Content Security Policy.

Comment: This is the right way to go, but the directive "frame-anscestors 'self';" should stop there, with a semicolon, not then continue to X-Frame-Options, which is meaningless in this header.

Answer (score 5):

Here is another thing to consider:

If you have a separate back-end and UI projects (as is very common for REST based sites), make sure that you put X-Frame-Options in the UI web.config. Your API is probably allowing cross site calls so adding the header to your API project would make no sense.

Answer (score 2):

I found that some file types (.asp and .htm files) were getting the X-Frame-Options header added by this mechanism and others (.js) weren't. Using the IIS Admin utility I removed the header from the application level and added it at the server level, and then all files were getting the header added.

Comment: The header is not appropriate for .js pages, which are not display media, but mere scripts.