# Angular: Refused to display '' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'sameorigin'

Tags: angular, iframe

I am writing an angular app, an internal utility for the company.

In one of my pages I want to display another page from another internal project, using an iframe.

```
<iframe src="https://......at/certificates" class="full"></iframe>
```

While running it the browser shows me this error:

```
Refused to display 'https://....at/' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'sameorigin'.
```

Any idea?

Thanks

Comment: If it's in the same Angular project, why are you using an iframe and not a component tag?

Comment: What do you mean component tag?

Comment: When you create a component in angular it has a selector - something like `app-my-component` you put that selector in html to create an instance of that component like `<app-my-component></app-my-component>`

Comment: No, sorry, I misled you. It's not the same angular ptoject.

Comment: The X-Frame Options header is a security feature that disallows other websites from 'stealing' a website in an iframe. You would need to remove that header from whatever hosting service is serving the other project.

Answer (score 0):

This should be done in the web server using the X-Frame-Options.

You should put the value "ALLOW-FROM domain" value to allow pages from your application to put the page in a iframe.

[With Apache see this link](https://tecadmin.net/configure-x-frame-options-apache/)

[With IIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25316781/x-frame-options-not-working-iis-web-config)

More info about this parameter [can be found here](https://javascript.info/clickjacking#x-frame-options)