# Can't display content in a frame

Tags: html, asp.net, iframe, webforms, meta-tags

I have a MVC application which I'm trying to display through an iframe.

I get following error message:

> This content cannot be displayed in a frame

I've googled some and found that I should use a meta tag. I've used it in my shared layout page in my MVC project but its still not working.

```
<meta http-equiv="X-Frame-Options" content="allow">
```

Rendered HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width"/>
    <meta http-equiv="X-Frame-Options" content="allow">
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

My iframe:

```
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainRegion" runat="server">
<div>
    <input type="hidden" name="nSystemId" value="<%= strSystemId %>" />
</div>
<iframe src="http://myServer/Project/Controller/" seamless="seamless" frameBorder="0" height="600" width="400"></iframe>    

</asp:Content>
```

Comment: Well, what actually *is* the content that your attempting to load?

Comment: @ChrisPratt Some forms etc.. I did found my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20254303/mvc-5-prevents-access-to-content-via-iframe

Comment: Found answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20254303/mvc-5-prevents-access-to-content-via-iframe