# IIS defaults X-Frame-Options Deny every time I publish my website

Tags: iis, msbuild, x-frame-options

I have a website running on IIs 8.5 on Windows 2012. Everytime I use Visual Studio 2015 to publish to this site, X-Frame-Options Deny is added.

I need this totally removed. I've found articles like [MVC 5 Prevents access to content via Iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20254303/mvc-5-prevents-access-to-content-via-iframe) suggesting to use:

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
    AntiForgeryConfig.SuppressXFrameOptionsHeader = true;
}
```

However, this does not work. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just noticed in IIS that at the server level, it had X-Frame-Options Deny. When I removed this, and republished to the site, X-Frame-Options did not appear.

It must have been inheriting from the server setting.