# Teams custom application AppStudio: how displaying a WebSite in personnal TAB

Tags: microsoft-teams, microsoft-appstudio

I'm working in Teams AppStudio, so I want to create a custom app with personal Tab witch display a website,

1. I have created my AppManifest correctly,
2. I have inserted my Personnal Tab: in this one I put my Website URL in content URL
   [image: personnal tab]
3. Then I deploy My App in My Teams application,
4. When I go to My App, I have any thing displayed in my personnal TAB,
   [image]

This the Error on browser:
teamsError on browser:
[image: teamsError on browser]

Comment: Did you added your website domain name in validDomain[] Array of app manifest?

Comment: there's a hyperlink inside the frame that says "Access _____" - where is that coming from? Is that not from your website?

Comment: @Trinetra-MSFT, Yes I do

Comment: @HiltonGiesenow, yes i have this Link in my TAB     'Access ......' it's shown above in the last screenshot

Comment: but if that's case, then I don't understand your original question, that you're having a problem displaying a website inside a tab - that IS your website, showing in the tab. What exactly is the problem?

Comment: @HiltonGiesenow, thank you, for you reply, my probleme is that my Web site is not displaying in the Personnal TAB, and when I click the link "Access ...." I get nothing, I try this in DeskTop teams client and in Browser also, nothing happen,,,, to be clair, My need is to create a custom application in appstudio,  this app allows me to display a WebSite on personnal TAB . Above I have explain the different steps that i have done.

Comment: Sure, I get your main requirement, but basically it -is showing- your website - there seems to be something wrong -inside- your website - what is that "Access" button wired up to do exactly?

Comment: @HiltonGiesenow, really, don't know where from comes this button, cause firstly I have used my Web site Url directly in URL content Tab, after , i change Ma thinking, I have used a web page (i haven"t any Link in this page, i put the redirection url function Windows.local.assign using the Js SDK for teams) to redirect my Tab to My webSite, then I get this link "Access ...."  in my TAB.

I'm using different WebSite Url to detect the problem, 

I get the same thing 'Blank Tab',,,, My WebSite is working well alone

Comment: this is the error, I get in browser " This content can’t be shown in a frame
There is supposed to be some content here, but the publisher doesn’t allow it to be displayed in a frame. This is to help protect the security of any information you might enter into this site."

Comment: Does your page implement the Teams JS library?

Comment: @HiltonGiesenow , Yes it does, when I try My script separatly (my page)  it works fine, But when i use this page like a Content url in my personnl TAB, it doesn't work.

Comment: ok thanks for clarifying - it's very important. If you see NOTHING from your own tab, that means a certain thing, but it can't be that. Can you send a screenshot of the error?

Comment: @HiltonGiesenow, Please how I can send this screenshot ?

Comment: Just edit your original question, and add it as a new image inside there

Comment: @HiltonGiesenow, You cant find it at the end of my issue description, thank you

Comment: ok, I see it now, that's much better, thanks. That's different from your first screenshot in the original question, which showed your page working fine. What is different? Is that a different page in your site? Did the " Access ..." button redirect the user to something else?

Comment: This might also be useful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50271878/this-content-cannot-be-viewed-in-a-frame-error-the-first-time-i-load-the-page

Comment: @HiltonGiesenow, In the 1st, screenshot, it show an HTML page witch has this link "Acces....  ", in the last One, I put directly my SIteWeb Homepage, then I have nothing displaying, I will see for this Link, thank you.

Comment: @HiltonGiesenow Thank you so much, it works fine know, I have made the change on My Website to allow displaying in an Iframe, and it works.

Comment: ok great, glad it's working