# Suppressing Default XFrameOptions in DNN

Tags: c#, asp.net, dotnetnuke, x-frame-options

I'm attempting to remove the default X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN header from DNN so I can allow iframes to link to my site.

I have found that the suggested way to do this is to use 
`AntiForgeryConfig.SuppressXFrameOptionsHeader = true`
(Source: [MVC 5 prevents access to content via Iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20254303/mvc-5-prevents-access-to-content-via-iframe))

However, because DNN does not have an accessible global.ascx.cs file I'm not sure how to add this.

It looks like someone else has successfully done this using a custom module:
https://www.dnnsoftware.com/forums/threadid/531595/scope/posts/remove-x-frame-options-value-of-sameorigin

I've tried doing the same, but it does not have the intended effect:

```
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Helpers;
using DotNetNuke.Entities.Modules;
using DotNetNuke.Entities.Modules.Actions;
using DotNetNuke.Services.Exceptions;

namespace DotNetNuke.Modules.IframeAllow
{

    public partial class IframeAllow : PortalModuleBase
    {        
        protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)

        {
            AntiForgeryConfig.SuppressXFrameOptionsHeader = true;

        }

    }

}
```

Possibly this is because this needs to happen at application start?

Answer (score 1):

You should change the X-Frame-Options on the web.config file by removing the header:

```
<httpProtocol>
  <customHeaders>
    <remove name="X-Frame-Options" />
  </customHeaders>
</httpProtocol>
```

Or by allowing a specific allowed origin (only 1 can be specified):

```
<httpProtocol>
  <customHeaders>
    <remove name="X-Frame-Options" />
    <add name="X-Frame-Options" value="ALLOW-FROM https://mywebsite.org/" />
  </customHeaders>
</httpProtocol>
```

Check this thread for more information https://www.dnnsoftware.com/forums/threadid/547624/scope/posts/how-to-allow-iframe-content-on-dnn-site-x-frame-option