# Asp.Net MVC site not showing in iFrame

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, iframe

I had an ASP.Net webpages site working fine (it's a booking application that people link to - a hosted service).

Some people just allowed a link to my site/application to open in a new window.  Other embeded it within an IFrame on their site.

I have started updating it to MVC - however, the MVC version no longer works within an IFrame.

Is there any way, within IIS7.5 or within the controllers in MVC, to allow my application/site to display wihin an iFrame?

Thank you,

Mark

Comment: Do you have an example of what it is or isn't doing? Are you getting an error? Off the top of my head I can't think of any reason that the server-side technology (WebForms vs. MVC) should make any difference.

Comment: Is MVC setting an X-Frame-Options response header automatically for you?

Comment: Hi - there is no error - the iframe window is just blank when looking at the MVC version. Also, there is no X-Frame-Options header being set - I checked that too, thanks.

Comment: @MarkTait how did you solve it?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this? Link below claims if the iframe's source site has the following css, it produces a blank iframe.

```
html{ position: relative; }
```

[Blank iFrame in IE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4444014/blank-iframe-in-ie)

I've used iframes inside MVC apps before, so they do work. But, I've only used them within the same domain.

Comment: Hi - thanks for the suggestion.  This is in Chrome - and different domains, so maybe some sort of inbuilt security feature.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like Microsoft.NET updated MVC to automatically write out a SAMEORIGIN X-Frame-Option header that would supersede any attempts you've made to add your own custom headers.

This other Stack Overflow answer gave me the solution:

[After update to MVC 5, iframe no longer works](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20253840/after-update-to-mvc-5-iframe-no-longer-works)

Also here's a blog post that details more about this issue:

[MVC5 prevents your website being loaded in an IFRAME](http://www.iambacon.co.uk/blog/mvc5-prevents-your-website-being-loaded-in-an-iframe)