# Iframe not showing website in Asp .Net MVC5

Tags: iframe, asp.net-mvc-5

Hi I am developing website using asp .net mvc5 but when I am using IFrame it is not showing any results. After googling and reading some documents I have found that MVC5 stops Iframe by default. I have found some answers on stackoverflow and other blogs but nothing works for me. Please check where I am doing mistake:

Here is my Code:

```
 public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
```

My View:

```
<iframe width="482" height="500" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" id="paymentFrame" src="http://www.codingfusion.com"></iframe>
```

I have tried following solutions so far:

[After update to MVC 5, iframe no longer works](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20253840/after-update-to-mvc-5-iframe-no-longer-works)

https://www.iambacon.co.uk/blog/mvc5-prevents-your-website-being-loaded-in-an-iframe

http://joost.haneveer.nl/asp-net/display-mvc-5-web-site-in-an-iframe/

Here is my Global.asax file:

```
  protected void Application_Start()
    {
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
        FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
        RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
        BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);

        //  MVC5 generates the "X-Frame-Options SAMEORIGIN" header by default, the following line disables the default behaviour
        System.Web.Helpers.AntiForgeryConfig.SuppressXFrameOptionsHeader = true;
    }

    protected void Application_BeginRequest()
    {
        Response.AddHeader("X-Frame-Options", "DENY");
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So finally I have solved my issue, I had followed wrong path from the beginning, There was no issue in showing websites using Iframe and MVC5 (I do not know how I walked on this path my be googling and trying solutions randomly). The real issue was:

My Domain consists of SSL (https://) and i was trying to display non SSL (http://) website. This causes cross origin and my Iframe is not working properly (how ever I can view complete code of the website by viewing source code of my page)

Solution: Luckily the website which I was trying to show in my Iframe supports SSL (https://) So I have only added (https://) to my Iframe source.

Answer (score 1):

just remove the following code:

```
protected void Application_BeginRequest()
    {
        Response.AddHeader("X-Frame-Options", "DENY");
    }
```

Comment: frame will be block by many option

like (application tier, network tier, firewall, or may be blocked by your ISP).

you just work with your application tier

Answer (score 0):

You're explicitly adding an `X-Frame-Options: DENY` header. Change that to `ALLOW-FROM http://foo.com`, where "foo.com" is the URL of the site where you are framing the site that sets this header. Then, you should be fine. Or, you can just not add the header at all here, since you're already suppressing it otherwise.

Comment: Thanks but it is not working, I have also tried removing Application_BeginRequest()